# Unable to execute table change event second time

Tags: java, sql, swing, events, user-interface

Here is a Controller Class of MVC:

```
    public class EventController extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {
    private EventModel model;
    private EventView  view;


    /** Constructor */
   public EventController(EventModel myModel, EventView myView){
       model = myModel;
       view = myView;     
    }

   public void setUpListeners() {
       this.view.addEventButton.addActionListener(this); 
       this.view.addEventMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
       this.view.editEventMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
       this.view.tableEvent.addMouseListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       Object button = e.getSource();
       if(button==this.view.addEventButton) {
           setEventDetails();          
       }
       else if (button==this.view.addEventMenuItem) {
           this.view.addDialog.setVisible(true);
       }
       else if(button==this.view.editEventMenuItem) {
           this.view.editDialog.setVisible(true);
       }

   }
   /*to change the display of label text of the VIEW according to the selected row of the table tableEvent*/

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
      int rowSelected = view.tableEvent.getSelectedRow();
      String tableClick = view.tableEvent.getModel().getValueAt(view.tableEvent.convertRowIndexToModel(rowSelected), 0).toString();
      Events e = model.getEvent(tableClick); //tell model to change its state based on user input on views 
      view.changeDisplay(e);
    }
```

Here is View Class and its changeDisplay() method to change label text appropriately:

```
public class EventView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private EventModel model;
public void changeDisplay(Events e) {
       evTitle.setText(""+e.getEventName());
       evWhen.setText("When: "+ e.getEventDate());
       evWhere.setText("Where: "+ e.getEventVenue());
       evDescription.setText("Description: "+ e.getEventDetail());
       evOpportunity.setText("Opporunity: "+ e.getEventOpportunity());
       evMoreDet.setText("More Details: "+ e.getEventMoreDetails());
   }


}
```

Here is Model Class:

```
 public class EventModel {
        Connection conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDB();
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Events e = new Events(); 

public void addEvent(String name, Date date,String start, String venue, String details,
String opportunity, String more, String end) throws SQLException {
    try {
    String qry = "INSERT INTO EVENT(eventName,date,time,venue,details,opportunity,moreDetails,endTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
    pst.setString(1, name);
    pst.setString(2, sdf.format(date));
    pst.setString(3, start);
    pst.setString(4, venue);
    pst.setString(5, details);
    pst.setString(6, opportunity);
    pst.setString(7, more);
    pst.setString(8, end);
    pst.executeUpdate(); 
    }
    finally{
       try{ pst.close(); } 
       catch (SQLException se) {}
      }
}



public Events getEvent(String tableClick) {


    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){      
        e.setEventName(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        e.setEventDate(rs.getString(3));
        e.setEventTime(rs.getString(4));
        e.setEventVenue(rs.getString(5));
        e.setEventDetail(rs.getString(6));
        e.setEventOpportunity(rs.getString(7));
        e.setEventMoreDetails(rs.getString(8));
        e.setEndTime(rs.getString(9));
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
       }
    } 
    catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return e;
} //end getEvent



}
```

[image: Clicking table row correctly changes label text]

My program is having a little error which I cant seem to fix for ages. Basically, whenever I click the row of the table (`tableEvent`) it should display the appropriate text in the labels next to the table as shown in the screenshot with the event "Software development careers event". This works fine on the first execution, but the `mouseClicked` event method in the controller does not change the display of the text after I've added an event through the `addEvent` method of the model. I am not sure what it is, whether I did something wrong with instantiation of an object of class `Events`, my `addEvent` method is wrong, or the actual `mouseClicked` overridden method in controller is wrong. What could it be?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that my answer helps you, but selection changes should be detected using `ListSelectionListener`. It's better because it provides reaction not only for the mouse clicks, but also for key events.
To add listener to your table simply use the selection model of the table:

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(myListener)
```

Probably this change helps you to solve your problem

Comment: But the thing is, it detects the selection change fine to begin with, but when the addEvent() is used, and then we back to selecting, it pauses and stop working and does not change display

Comment: Is table model up-to-date after adding of the event?

Comment: yes the table would display the new added data straight away, but then when clicked nothing displays. am i doing something wrong in addEvent() thats not allowing it reuse mouseClick as before?

Comment: Well, the code looks dangerous. Probably you get an exception on adding of the event? I think you should try to debug your application.  Without debugging of the complete code I cannot say what's wrong.

Comment: hmm debugger just points to `pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");` line

Comment: its solved, a connection was closed elsewhere oops so method `pst=conn...` had no connection

Comment: Great! But you should read some articles about Swing. So you can make your UI better.